# oauth token_rejected when authenticating with quickbooks api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth

I followed the directions on http://minimul.com/integrating-rails-and-quickbooks-online-via-the-version-3-api-part-1.html and am receiving 'token_rejected' after authentication with quickbooks:

```
OAuth::Problem in VendorsController#oauth_callback

token_rejected

Request

Parameters:

{"oauth_token"=>"blah",
 "oauth_verifier"=>"blah",
 "realmId"=>"blah",
 "dataSource"=>"QBO"}

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#vendors_controller.rb:
... 
def oauth_callback
  at = session[:qb_request_token].get_access_token(:oauth_verifier => params[:oauth_verifier])
  token = at.token
  secret = at.secret
  realm_id = params['realmId']
  redirect_to 'vendors/index', notice: "Your QuickBooks account has been successfully linked."
end
...
```

The traceroute defines "at = session[:qb_request_token]...." as the line that throws the error. Any ideas?
Rails 3.1.3 - ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-linux]

Answer (score 0):

The error means the Access Token was not found, was expired or is invalid. I would try refreshing the Access Token.